# Nuxt.js Create pages, available with the only specific locale (defined on my own)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Is there way in nuxt.js to create pages which will be available only with one locale?
Example:
Available locales: en(default), ru, es, de.
Page name is `new-mrz-reader`.
I want page to be available only by `/ru/new-mrz-reader`, not by `/de/new-mrz-reader`, not by `/es/new-mrz-reader` or `/new-mrz-reader`.
I want to automate this process for future pages.

Comment: https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/routing.html#ignore-routes  --  i found this. And this works.